# Micronaut Deployed in Heroku facing error?

Tags: heroku, micronaut

I got success message in heroku console but my program is not running

Github code : https://github.com/boxercool/demo

```
          [INFO] Total time:  9.780 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-09T05:54:33Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 63.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
       https://poorvikademo.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Please post heroku logs as well..

Comment: @AmitB10   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DxWW6n_UEX5t4UVQfF51APUc1EYUUzR2zQC4j7ovJpc/edit?usp=sharing  please check this link